# How can I make my server accessible from all wi-fi networks?

Tags: tomcat, wifi, server, connectivity, sesame

I have a website that queries a server on my machine. I have made a firewall exception that enables any computer to access the server (or I thought so).

I have accessed the server from several public wi-fi networks without any issues. However, I am unable to connect from an airport wi-fi. I used TeamViewer  to remotely log into the server machine and found that the website works ok there.

Is there a way to make sure that people from all networks can access the page? I'm not sure why an airport wi-fi wouldn't let me access the server when it doesn't appear to block anything else. Please help.

Comment: What port does your website run on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Airport wifis and other public wifis often block access to any port other than default http (80). If your website is running on a different port (8080, for example), it might be blocked. The fix is to reconfigure your server so that the site is accessible from port 80.